# How to recrop the selected image in android?

Tags: java, android

I am cropping the selected image from gallery or camera successfully by using the following source code. But I want to recrop the selected image without capturing the image again. Could you please anyone guide me to do this task

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'


     btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            clearData();

            CropImage.activity().start(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });


@Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){


            CropImage.ActivityResult result = 
            CropImage.getActivityResult(data);


            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                picUri = result.getUri();


                imageview.setImageURI(picUri);

                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = 
                (BitmapDrawable)imageview.getDrawable();
                bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

                saveFaceToGallery();
                showTextfromImage();

            }

            else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
            {

                Exception e = result.getError();

            }

        }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot undo the crop operation by using this library because it saved the cropped image in the app's cache folder and also returns the Uri of the original image. So, you can write your own logic after cropping an image of whether to select the cropped image or the original one.

Comment: simply make image pick request from gallery and you can do that on it

Comment: I am new to android. could you please share any useful links